# Notify with JSON payload from a query result

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to make a trigger which runs a query, encodes the query results as JSON text, and sends it with a notify.

Here's some pseudo code for what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TYPE client_update_tile AS (
    x integer,
    y integer,
    state_id integer
);

CREATE FUNCTION world.notify_viewport_shift()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
        payload text;
    BEGIN
        SELECT to_json_text(world.get_player_update_tiles()) INTO payload;
        SELECT pg_notify('players', payload);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `world.get_player_update_tiles` function returns a `SETOF client_update_tile`.

I made up the `to_json_text` function to explain what I mean. I just want to be able to convert the results of a query to JSON text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
SELECT json_array_agg(to_json(*))::text INTO payload FROM world.get_player_update_tiles();
```

or

```
SELECT to_json(ARRAY(SELECT world.get_player_update_tiles()))::text INTO payload;
```

Comment: Had to do `ARRAY(SELECT world.get_player_update_tiles())`, but that works! Thank you.